# Are interception hard to defend in football because offense is playing?

Tags: american-football

I know there are 2 teams in football the defense and offense.  I'm just thinking it would be really hard to defend after your team gets intercepted because the people on the field don't really play defense often and they are probably not that good at it.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but no - as an exact corrolary to your observation, the intercepting team don't really play offense often and they are probably not that good at it, so to first order it all balances out.